# Open source CBIR with SIFT or Harris-Laplace descriptors?

Tags: sift, cbir

Does anyone know a open source CBIR that use SIFT or Harris-Laplace descriptors?

Comment: I think you might have already googled. Just in case you didn't see, some of the open source CBIR engines are listed here: 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_CBIR_engines
It would be useful to have a look and find out.